# opengl and Texture mapping with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, opentk

I use OpenTK with VB.net and I want to add the texture mapping to my code, with the following steps:

1: Loading the texture:

```
Protected Sub LoadTexture(ByVal textureId As Integer, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(filename)
    Dim data As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId)
    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,
                  bmp.Width, bmp.Height, 0, OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra,
                  PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0)

    bmp.UnlockBits(data)
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, TextureMinFilter.Linear)
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, TextureMagFilter.Linear)
End Sub
```

2: Enabling and adding:

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D)
GL.GenTextures(textures.Length, textures)
LoadTexture(textures(0), "bricks.bmp")
```

3: Painting (with GlControl1 loaded, in the GlControl1 Paint):

```
GL.PushMatrix()
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textures(0))
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, TextureMinFilter.Linear)
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, TextureMagFilter.Linear)
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads)
GL.Color3(Color.White)
GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
GL.Vertex3(200, 0, 200)
GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
GL.Vertex3(200, 100, 200)
GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
GL.Vertex3(200, 100, -200)
GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
GL.Vertex3(200, 0, -200)
GL.End()
GL.PopMatrix()
```

When i run my code, I get this error: `argument Exception was unhandled` for this line `Dim bmp As New Bitmap(filename)`.

the exception is (parameter is not valid) like the images

[Try And Catch exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f139C.png) 

note : I added the image in the root file like this
[the Image Place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w3qj.png)

I used opengl and texture in c++ but I don't have this problem ,my be the error can be in Loading texture function or in another place

the all code :

```
Imports OpenTK
Imports OpenTK.Graphics
Imports OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing


Public Class Form2

Dim loaded As Boolean = False
Protected textures(2) As Integer

Protected Sub LoadTexture(ByVal textureId As Integer, ByVal filename As String)
    Try


        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(filename)

        Dim data As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId)
        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,
                      bmp.Width, bmp.Height, 0, OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra,
                      PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0)


        bmp.UnlockBits(data)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, TextureMinFilter.Linear)
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, TextureMagFilter.Linear)

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    GL.ClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D)

    LoadTextures()
End Sub
Protected Sub LoadTextures()
    GL.GenTextures(textures.Length, textures)
    LoadTexture(textures(0), "bricks.bmp")
End Sub

Private Sub GlControl1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GlControl1.Load

    GL.ClearColor(Color.Black)

    loaded = True


End Sub
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged

    GlControl1.Invalidate()
End Sub
Private Sub NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged

    GlControl1.Invalidate()
End Sub
Private Sub GlControl1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.Paint

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)


    Dim perspective As Matrix4 = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.04, 4 / 3, 1, 10000)
    Dim lookat As Matrix4 = Matrix4.LookAt(10, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(perspective)
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(lookat)
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, GlControl1.Width, GlControl1.Height)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less)



    GL.Rotate(NumericUpDown1.Value, 0, 0, 1)
    GL.Rotate(NumericUpDown2.Value, 0, 1, 0)

    GL.PushMatrix()

    GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads)
    GL.Color3(Color.White)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(200, 0, 200)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(200, 100, 200)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(200, 100, -200)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(200, 0, -200)
    GL.End()
    GL.PopMatrix()



    GraphicsContext.CurrentContext.VSync = True
    GlControl1.SwapBuffers()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have edited your question slightly to make it more readable. Feel free to further improve the question! If you can, please provide more information related to the exception you are getting (I could imagine that it may be due to the BMP file). You could wrap the `LoadTexture` procedure contents in a [Try-Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) block to get access to the exception.

Comment: thank you very much ... i'm so sorry i'm weak in English and this is my first time in stackOverflow ...
 Note: i'm improve the question